# 1-dimensional p-divisible groups, level structures and Cartier divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am confused about the 1-dimensionality of $p$-divisible groups and its role in defining level structures.

Here's how I view/understand/*not* understand things:

If a $p$-divisible group arises from a dimension $g$ abelian variety (say over some $S$ over $\mathbb F_p$), then it is of height $2g$ and dimension at least $g$, with equality in the ordinary case.

So for $g>1$, such $p$-divisible groups are never 1-dimensional and if $g=1$, they are of height 2.

On the other hand, from what I've been reading, whenever a good notion of level structure is mentioned, the assumption is usually that the $p$-divisible group is 1-dimensional. I am still confused as to *why*. I understand it should be related to the fact that Cartier divisors *make sense* but am not entirely sure what is the ambient curve since such $p$-divisible groups do not arise from abelian varieties..

I am familiar with Katz-Mazur's definition of level structure/full set of sections, I understand Drinfeld modules and the notion of level structure (in that case the Drinfeld module *is* 1-dimensional over the base so Cartier divisors make sense etc). I am however confused how this all relates among each other... in the etale case a level structure seems to be a choice of isomorphism with the constant group scheme, but then there is also a notion of level structure for formal $p$-divisible groups, and I've usually interpreted (maybe erroneously?) "formal" roughly as being "connected"?; but then over a perfect base (say a perfect field) there are no sections and then any level structure is trivial?.. I really hope this brief rambling exposes to an expert where my confusion is..

As an example of an explicit question, on page 20 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.2558.pdf to a Drinfeld level structure $\varphi:\mathbb F_p^d\to X_0[p]$ a filtration is defined by the equality of divisors $[H_i]=\displaystyle\sum_{x\in\text{span}(e_1,\ldots,e_i)}[\varphi(x)]$. **Q:** Where do these divisors "live" and where exactly is 1-dimensionality used?

Any illuminating comments/answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:** By dimension of a $p$-divisible groups I mean the (locally constant) rank of the Lie algebra (such as in Messing, or page 59 of Harris-Taylor "The Geometry and Cohomology of Some Simple Shimura Varieties"). In particular the height can be any integer $h\ge1$. The arxiv paper referenced above works with higher height 1-dimensional groups, which shouldn't arise from abelian varieties, yet speaks of Cartier divisors, hence my confusion as I don't know on which ambient scheme these live on.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of “dimension” is different to mine, but by my definition, the dimension of the $p$-divisible of a $g$-dimensional Abelian variety is always just $g$.

Comment: Also I believe the formality in "formal $p$-divisible group" is in reference to formal groups -- look up formal schemes (formal groups are essentially formal schemes with additional structure) if you want an introduction to formal groups from a geometric point of view.

Comment: Thanks @Lubin and Jeff. I apologize for not being clear in my original question. I will edit. By dimension of a $p$-divisible groups I mean the (locally constant) rank of the Lie algebra (such as in Messing, or page 59 of Harris-Taylor "The Geometry and Cohomology of Some Simple Shimura Varieties"

Comment: About the comment "higher height 1-dimensional groups, which shouldn't arise from abelian varieties": I think they do! It seems to me that they can arise as summands in the p-div'l group of an abelian variety, just not as the whole p-div'l group. For example, an abelian 3-fold over the algebraic closure of F_p can have p-div'l group G_{1/3} + G_{2/3}, where G_{r/s} has dimension r and height s. So there's a height 3 1-dim'l formal group showing up in the p-div'l group of an abelian variety.  I really like chapter 4 of Demazure's "Lectures on p-div'l groups" as a reference for this material.

Comment: Perfectly right, @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.

Comment: Thanks @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, I am still confused about the following: so $G$ ($=G_{1/3}$) appears as a summand in the $p$-div gp of an abelian variety. But isn't this ab. var. of dim $g=3$, making the notion of level structure badly behaved? (as points are not Cartier divisors, just 0-cycles - for example as mentioned in 1.1 of the Introduction in https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374734?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents ) So how does $G=G_{1/3}$ being one-dimensional help in having a good notion of level structure? I really hope what I am asking makes sense, I might just be misunderstanding things...

Comment: This does not answer your question, but another example of 1-dimensional p-divisible groups arising as summands of p-divisible groups associated to abelian varieties comes from (for example) the theory of PEL Shimura varieties. There's a nice (homotopy-theoretically oriented) overview in sections 12 and onwards in Tyler Lawson's "An overview of abelian varieties in homotopy theory". (Note that the phrase "level structure" there does *not* mean Drinfel'd level structure.) I don't know anything about level structures on abelian varieties of dimension >1, unfortunately.

Comment: Expanding on what you see in Lawson's overview paper mentioned by @skd, there is a treatment of level structures on abelian varieties of dimension >1 in section 3.3 of Behrens and Lawson's "Topological automorphic forms." It manages to be very simple by defining away (in a way that's quite appropriate for their situation) potential difficulties: their abelian varieties are assumed to admit uniformizations, level structures then can simply be understood in terms of lattice automorphisms. My understanding is that the level structures constructed in their monograph are prime-to-p...

Comment: ...and consequently they don't give Drinfeld level structures on the resulting formal groups. What @aytio is asking about, and what you see e.g. in the Chai-Norman paper aytio cited, seems to be the more difficult situation: if your level structures are not prime-to-p, it's not obvious to me how the level structure on the abelian variety (defined geometrically, e.g. in terms of a given uniformization) relates to a Drinfeld level structure on the formal group, although I think the 1-dim'l case is handled in "Elliptic modules." Sorry I can't be more helpful with higher-dim'l level structures!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer -- in particular, I'm not familiar enough with Drinfeld modules to comment on that part of your question -- but perhaps I can clear up a bit of your confusion.

It's true that the height of the $p$-divisible group $G$ coming from an abelian variety of dimension $g$ is always equal to $2g$, while the height $h$ of the identity component $G_0$ of the $G$ satisfies $g \leq h \leq 2g$ (the extremes $h = g$ and $h = 2g$ correspond to the ordinary and supersingular cases respectively). This reflects the fact that the kernel of the multiplication-by-$p$ map has order $p^{2g}$, but pointwise (the etale part) it has some lower $\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$-rank, namely $2g - h$. It seems that what you are defining the dimension is what sources I've seen define as the height of $G_0$, and the dimension is actually always $g$ as Lubin has commented.

Then the reason sources that discuss level structures tend to assume dimension $1$ is probably that most study of moduli spaces of level structures treats the elliptic curve (or $1$-dimensional) case.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Unfortunately, that's not what I mean by dimension. I've edited the question to include the definition I am using. It is not merely the height of the connected part. For example over an algebraically closed field (perfect probably suffices) $K$, for every integer $h\ge1$, there is a unique connected *1-dimensional* $p$-divisible group of height $h$, typically denoted $\Sigma_{K,h}$ (for example, page 3, Prop. 1 of http://www.its.caltech.edu/~mantovan/papers/Igusa.pdf )